# Using JQuery .serialize() to combine form elements with the same name?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have the below form input elements, each with the same name of "rating" as shown below.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="5" id="rating5_2053" name="rating">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" id="rating4_2053" name="rating">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3" id="rating3_2053" name="rating">

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2" id="rating2_2053" name="rating">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" id="rating1_2053" name="rating">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="0" id="rating0_2053" name="rating">
```

When using

```
$form.serialize();
```

and submitting the form,

EDIT: Using JQuery Serialize() result and manipulating the querystring for the GET request, it ends up like the below:

```
&rating=5&rating=4&rating=3&rating=2&rating=1&rating=0
```

There is good reason for it to do this, but in my case I don't need to do that.

I wanted to know if there is a way I can configure this to do the below instead?

```
&rating=5,4,3,2,1,0
```

Thanks

Comment: Really simple, just switch the name to "rating[]" and implode the rating array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I can't change the field names.

Comment: In your inputs, the `name` attribute? If you set it up as an array it can handle the multiple values without colliding as your query string does.

Comment: @MetalFrog thanks! I had this problem and was able to change the field names. very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go

```
var ratingData = [],
    data = $('form').find('input:not([name="rating"])').serialize();
$('form').find('input[name="rating"]').each(function(){
    ratingData.push(this.value);
});
data += '&rating='+ratingData.join(',');
console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ejf45/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was is there a way to configure JQuery Serialize() to do this? as my form has more elements in that I haven't shown. I'm starting to think that I have to manipulate the resulting string that Serialize() gives me.

Comment: No, `serialize` doesn't take any parameters: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ although I just edited the question to do what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try something like this :)**

```
var ratings="rating=";

$('input[name="rating"]:checked').each(function(){ 

    var temp = $(this).val();

    ratings = ratings+ temp +",";

});

alert(ratings);​
```

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/k7G64/)

Comment: Please note that the `[@` attribute selector was removed in 1.3 (more than 3 years ago).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question was, is there a way to configure JQuery Serialize() to do this? as my form has more elements in, that I haven't shown. I'm starting to think that I have to manipulate the resulting string that Serialize() gives me?

Comment: Ya you are right then you need to capture the query string after serializing..
And perform 
var string = queryString;
string = string.replace('&rating=',',');
now post with the new string